# Keep getting error while creating react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have been trying to create a react app, so basically a new project such as hello world or anything.

I try using `npx create-react-app my-app`

The error I get is:

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.0, which is behind the latest release (4.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

I try following those steps and even uninstalled using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` but I still keep getting the same error.

My npm version: 6.14.8

This is such a basic process to create a first application in react I am not sure why is it so complicated. Could someone please tell how can I fix that error and also how can I create an react app smoothly?

If more information is needed please feel free to comment down below:)

Comment: Try updating to the latest `npm` version `npm install -g npm@latest`.

Comment: @theWellHopeErr I already have it updated to latest version. I did use that command before and checked it again like you said, it's updated to same version I wrote in my question :(

Comment: have you tried uninstalling globally installed instance of create-react-app

Comment: @KetanRamteke Did you mean using this command `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` if so, yes I try uninstalling it using the above command, but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning cache? Try this: npm cache clean --force and then try again.

Comment: @KirankumarAmbati I tried it, but it still gives the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Solution 1:


Try this:

1. Clear cache: `npm cache clean --force`
2. Remove: `\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`
3. Run: `npm install -g npm@latest`
4. And try running:
`npx create-react-app my-app`
or
`npm init react-app my-app`

Solution 2:

Steps 1,2,3 as above.
Step 4: `npm i create-react-app -g`
Step 5: Then try running: `create-react-app my-app`

Let me know if any of this works !

Comment: how do I remove in 2nd step? Is there any command for it? @KirankumarAmbati

Comment: Normal folder deletion should be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Above fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

Worked for me:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app app-name
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this command. It worked

1. npm install -g create-react-app
2. npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for your answer, contributions are very much appreciated! A quick note - to further help as you are trying to do a little more information would helpful, such as your `npm --version`, `npx --version`, `node --version` as well as the version intalled of create-react-app. This seems to be a version related problem so since you have a working setp that information can be vital to finding the answer. Have a great rest of your night and let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. So what I did is:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install create-react-app --save
npx create-react-app my-app
```

and it worked. The second line, I think, is to have `create-react-app` locally.

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry ,it can be  fixed  by installing  create-react-app globally
run these  two lines  and  it  can be  fixed

```
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app your-app
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following command.

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

then

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Afterwards you should be good to go with `npx create-react-app my-app` :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below command for creation of new project.

```
npx create-react-app applicationname
```

Answer (score 0):

I put in the code npm uninstall -g create-react-app
and I get the below its not deleted anything
PS C:\Users\deann> npm uninstall -g create-react-app

up to date, audited 1 package in 435ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

then I put

PS C:\Users\deann> npm install create-react-app
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

added 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 4s

4 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

3 high severity vulnerabilities

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The two commands helped me when I came across with this issue.

npm uninstall -g create-react-app - this uninstalles the old version

npm install -g create-react-app - this installes the new version

then put the command
npx create-react-app name-of-folder